# fancybox2 doesnt load. noConflict advice needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I've decided to upgrade to fancybox2.1.5 (had 1.3.4). I cant get it to init.

*I have deleted my original question (about what I tested) because I have found out what the problem is.*

Turns out the problem is **tinymce** and **fancybox** together. If I only use one of those on a page, no problem. If both get init on 1 page, fancybox wont work. I need noConflict, but cant get it the way I want.

I'm bulding this into an excisting CMS. The `$.noConflict()` solution combined with using all jquery selecters `jQuery('#likeThis')` is **not** an option. I want the noConflict code applied wrapper-like arround the tinymce's.

I've moved all tinymce related inits to a seperate js-file.
I tried the noConflict at the beginning, and moving it back again, but no luck there:

```
jQuery.noConflict(); // also tried adding true here
 /* 
 tinymce's here with jQuery('selector').tinymce() 
  */
var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); // also tried without 'var', also tried adding true here
```

Also tried this:

```
// Other scripts
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script src="/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
<script src="/beheer/admin/script/tinymces.js"></script>
<script>var $ = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
// Other scripts & code
```

In short: I want to be able to use `$` everywhere, and keep using that, but 'sandbox' the tinymce's, how do I do that?

Comment: hey it's working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/limdauto/VTdsj/ Maybe there's an error elsewhere in your javascript that blocks the initialization?

Comment: Well, I thought so, thats why I added the `console.log`'s before and after the init. I have all JS in a central location, so there should be no mix-ups. Gonna continue tomorrow, the lack of views here suggest I might not get allot more out of this :P

Comment: this is the typical case when sharing a link to a demo that reproduces the issue will help to get help (no offense but we may see errors you don't ;) also, what browsers this is not working with?

Comment: Yes, but I dont think I can reproduce this in a fiddle. It's too complex, and Lim got a small version working. Im checking it with firefox 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was updating the Tinymce. I had version 3.4.7 and replaced it with a 3.5.7 version. After that, no problems anymore.